# Is accessing outer class private variables from private inner class a bad practice?

Tags: java, class, private, nested-class

Suppose we have

```
public class parent {
    private string x;
    private class child {
         void doSomething(){
              System.out.println(x);
         }
    }
}
```

Of course this is a trivial example, but in general should I use private variables from the outer class like this, or should I avoid this and pass them to the inner class through parameters in the constructor?

Comment: Can it be done, for sure, should it be done, that's a broad question which would require more context.  The issue you have to answer is, will changing the value adversely affect the state of the class?  You have a question of responsibility and control.  Would it be better to use setters/getters instead?  What happens if the `parent` class extended? How does that affect the extendability of the base class and what effects might it have for child classes? Personally, I prefer to rely on methods to access/modify the properties, but that might not be applicable to your particular use case...

Comment: I would like to add that it is fine as long as you never pass instances of the private inner class outside the parent class using an interface or superclass type (to prevent access violations). In addition, methods in the private inner class are more complicated than methods in the parent class, because there may be more than one instance of the private inner class per parent class and they may be fighting for control of the instance variable. So its probably best to only read the values unless there is only one instance of the private inner class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality might not be the same. If the instance variables get re-assigned, passing them to the constructor would change the functionality. And having two copies makes the code harder to read.

If the instance variables don't change and the classes really go together, it is probably fine. Make sure that the inner class really should be one. You are coupling the classes tightly with this technique which makes refactoring harder.

For event handlers (a common inner class type) and the like, accessing the outer class' variables is common and logical.